# getting vimeo id codes from album

Tags: php, curl, vimeo

Trying to call get an array of ALL videos from a Vimeo Album. Using vimeo's JS API.

https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/simple#album-request

So the doc above says that to access information about a vimeo album you form a url like this:

`http://vimeo.com/api/v2/album/album_id/request.output`

and in my case that url looks like this:

`$id2 = $_POST['alb1']`

`http://vimeo.com/api/v2/album/$id2/info.php`

So everone says to use CURL to read the .php file that vimeo provides using the above url.

From it, i need to aquire the total number of videos in the album.

With that number I need to create a loop that accesses all the videos (for as long as the album is) and saves it as an array full of the video URLs.

That is then saved to a SQL database and the database is read out in a loop to print out `<li>`lines with an image of the video in it.

See it all in NON action here:

http://s199881165.onlinehome.us/transfem/newlayout/getal.php

here's the php I use to read the vimeo file

```
function getVimeoInfo($id, $info) 
{

    if (!function_exists('curl_init')) die('CURL is not installed!');
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://vimeo.com/api/v2/album/$id/videos.php");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    $output = unserialize(curl_exec($ch));
    $output = $output[0][$info];
    curl_close($ch);                
    return $output;                             

}


function getVimeoInfo2($id2, $info2) 
{

    if (!function_exists('curl_init')) die('CURL is not installed!');
    $ch2 = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, "http://vimeo.com/api/v2/album/$id2/info.php");
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    $output2 = unserialize(curl_exec($ch2));
    $output2 = $output2[0][$info2];
    curl_close($ch2);               
    return $output2;                                

}
```

Here is the other part:

```
    $thetoatslotzes = getVimeoInfo2($posty_alby,'total_videos');
    echo "<script> alert('lotze: " . $thetoatslotzes . "');</script>" ; 


    $albarray =     getVimeoInfo($_POST['alb1'],'url');
    echo "<script> alert('albarray: " . $thetoatslotzes . "');</script>" ; 



      $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

      $dbh->beginTransaction();

      $dbh->exec("TRUNCATE TABLE vim_playlist12");
                $dbh->commit();


      $i = 0;

      while($i < 9) {
      $eye_matee =  $i + 1; 

      $dbh->beginTransaction();

      $dbh->exec("insert into vim_playlist12 (url, listnum) values 
      ($albarray[$i], $eye_matee)");

      $i = $i + 1; 

        $dbh->commit();
      }




       $seleccion = 'SELECT url, listnum FROM vim_playlist12 ORDER BY listnum';
foreach ($dbh->query($seleccion) as $row) {
    print $row['listnum'] . ": " . $row['url'] . "<br>" ;

}

    } 
    catch (Exception $e) {
      $dbh->rollBack();
      echo "Failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

}
else 
{}
```

So ultimately if I can get that array of URLS from the vimeo videos.php i'll be in good shape.

Comment: vimeo has a [PHP Library](https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/advanced#php-library) for download that might help. I've used their library and its quite nice and gets the job done without coding many lines of code.

Comment: mmm i am looking at that and it seems WAYY over my head, it also seems like it is used for accessing user information, no? For instance in order to include the vimeo.php file you need an api key, etc.